# personalize AIR app installation

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

I'm installing an Air app on windows that installs a personalized xml in the app's Program Files folder (i.e. C:\Program Files\app\config.xml)

After installation I have to manually edit this file each time (editing settings for user name, server ip, etc...)

So, I wonder what is the way to go if I want to edit this file under the installation?

Compiling the app in Flash CS5.5 with actionscript 3

/thanks
/javier

Comment: rather than adding the xml file during installation, you could create it the first time the app runs. ie: if it doesnt exist, create and save it; if it does exist, load it. see http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the installation folder via :

```
File.applicationDirectory
```

But your app hasn't write permissions on the folder.
You should use :

```
File.applicationStorageDirectory
```

Like Lee Burrows said, you could create the file at the first application run.

Example:

```
var configFile:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvepath('config.xml');
if(configFile.exists)
{
    // load file
}
else
{
    // apply default settings + save settings to "configFile"
}
```